# What are the approaches I could take for removing top 20 or 30 lines from textfile each time the button is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, text-files

I am learning c# textfile handling and string manipulation,  I want to take suggestions on most prefered method of removing lines from textfile on button click. Suppose, I have a text file with 300 lines and I want to remove 1st 30 lines from that textfile each time the button the is click and show the filtered items in listbox.

this is what I tried, but unable to get it right..

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);

                var newLines = File.ReadAllLines(file).Skip(30);
                File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
                foreach (string line in text)
                {


                    listBox1.Items.Add(line);


                }
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite the whole file. A readable way is using [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) +  [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is part of `System.Linq`:

```
var newLines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(30);
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

Comment: Thank you @tim, is their any other method, where one can skip 30 lines each time the button is clicked rather than rewriting the entire file and skipping the top 30 lines, for instance, when the button is clicked for 1st time its (300 - 30) when its clicked 2nd time its (300 - 60) and so on.

Comment: @user2889827: but it's already working this way. Every time you click the button the first 30 lines are omitted. Since you're rewriting the file you get 1) 300 - 30 2) 300 - 60 3) 300 - 90  etc.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Schmelter giving it a try.

Comment: I am unable to get it right, i wrote a user file upload script and listing all lines in listbox and confused how to incorporate this

Comment: @user2889827: where did you get stuck? Do you get an exception? The code above works as it is. You just need to provide the path to the text-file and everytime you call it (f.e. in a method) it will remove the first 30 lines from the file.

Comment: hi @Tim Schmelter I am edited my post with my codes,

Comment: You just have to replace my variable `path` with your variable `file`.

Comment: yup i did, but its not working in the manner it was intended, maybe because, each time i am clicking the button a new file dialogue pops up, i need to create different button, and run the function on button click, and each time i click the button, listbox item is decresed by 30. any help please